# How to create Photoshop.exe desktop shortcut using Wine?

Tags: 14.04, wine

I have wine 1.7.28 installed, then i've installed Photoshop CC. But i can't figure out on how to create a desktop shortcut.

I've tried creating photoshop.desktop with following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Photoshop CC
Comment=Photoshop CC 32-bit
Exec=env wine32 wine "C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Photoshop CC 2014 (32 Bit)\\Photoshop.exe"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=photoshop
Categories=Graphics;
```

And placed that file under /home/username/Desktop. Did a:

```
chmod 700 photoshop.desktop
```

wine32 - is a working alias to:

```
alias wine32="WINEPREFIX='/home/username/.wine32'"
```

But nothing happens when i double click on that shortcut. However i can launch Photoshop.exe from wine directory: `.wine32/drive_c/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CC 2014 (32 Bit)/Photoshop.exe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases don't work in desktop files (or in scripts in general, unless enabled in the script). You should expand it out:

```
env WINEPREFIX='/home/username/.wine32' wine "C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Photoshop CC 2014 (32 Bit)\\Photoshop.exe"
```

(And perhaps add `WINEARCH=win32` to the environment.)

In the long run, it's simpler not to use shell-specific features in desktop files. If you feel the need for one, create a script and give the path to the script in the `Exec` line.

Comment: Didn't know that aliases aren't working in a desktop file. Thanks, now it works!